# How to calculate the probability that something happens exactly a certain number of times in a specific number of independent cases given probability?

Tags: statistics

I am attempting to help my friend with statistics homework, but I never took statistics. She doesn't really have another person to ask and since I'm pretty good at math I figured I would try to figure it out. This problem has me stumped, however. I don't want to just be given the answers to the homework so I am going to present an example question:

Let's say that when a magic coin is flipped, it can land heads or tails like any other coin. However, this coin is magic and is rigged in favor of a specific side. The coin can only land on heads 1/250 flips. In 5 independent cases, what is the probability that exactly 4 land as tails?

No need to actually solve the problem, just tell me how to do this specific kind of problem. I just didn't know how to word it without providing a specific example.

Comment: See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Comment: I have never seen that Wikipedia article and the example they use is also about a biased coin! Thank you!